# Data binding in wpf with expression in getter

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a property in my model which has getter

```
public boolean Status {
    get {
        return 1==2;
    }
}
```

and a label

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=Status, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

I would like to monitor the Status. Now when the Status value is changed UI does not get updated with the value.

Comment: give it a private set? also, 1==2 wil always return false, how do you even set the value in the first place?

Comment: 1==2 is just for an example.

Comment: You need to explain what you're doing. Better. If the status is dependent on numerous factors then raise propertychanged with "Status" as a parameter when any of those changes. If whatever you're doing is on a different thread to the ui then you will need to dispatcher invokeasync to get from that thread to the ui since propertychanged has thread affinity. Propertychanged must be raised from the parent object so you might need to wrap your logic or property using a public property in the viewmodel rather than model.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming, that view model already implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, you must raise `PropertyChanged` event, if you want UI to re-read property value. It doesn't matter if this is get-only property or get/set one.

Since it's get-only, you need to call `OnPropertyChanged` after you change something, that affects getter expression result:

```
private int a;
private int b;

public bool Status => a == b;

private void DoSomething()
{
    a = ...;
    b = ...;

    // ...

    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Status));
}
```

Comment: I can run a thread to monitor the Status property and call OnPropertyChanged to update the UI. Is there any simple way by which I can achieve this (possibly from xaml itself)

Comment: @Azeeb: simple way is to call `OnPropertyChanged`. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do two things:

1. Implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface in class which contains the Status property.
2. Call the PropertyChanged handler and call that method in the setter of the Status property which you will implement as a part of INotifyPropertyChanged - if you don't what it is, please google it and you will get the piece of code - it basically notifies the UI that a property has changed.
3. If the Status property is only get then you will have to call the PropertyChanged method after you know that the status has been updated.